# Firebase - Saving data

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a question regarding the firebase.

I'm developing an app where there are three screens: the '**registration screen**' where the user will create an account with email and password. The '**building profile screen**', where the user will answer some questions to be implemented in his profile, (such as "What's your name?"). And finally the '**profile screen**', where the user information will be displayed, such as the user name.

On the '**registration screen**' I'm having no problem, the user fills in the email input and password input, and by clicking "create account", calling .createUserWithEmailAndPassword, the user account is created and it is taken to the '**building profile screen**'. The question I'm having is in the '**building profile screen**'. My question is: How can I save the user name and other data? 
I read some articles on the subject but I had difficulty understanding. Can any of you guys help me with this?

Comment: Where are you saving the data? The database?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create a node or multiple nodes in firebase for each user to hold their user-specific information.  The database structure could be uniform like so:

```
users: {
  uid_a: {
    username: 'uid_as_username',
    email: 'uid_as_email',
    name: 'uid_as_name',
    other_attribute: 'uid_as_other_attribute_value'
    [,...]
  },
  uid_b: {
    username: 'uid_bs_username',
    email: 'uid_bs_email',
    name: 'uid_bs_name',
    other_attribute: 'uid_bs_other_attribute_value'
    [,...]
  }
  [,...]
}
```

or split up like so:

```
usernames: {
  uid_a: 'uid_as_username',
  uid_b: 'uid_bs_username'
  [,...]
},
emails: {
  uid_a: 'uid_as_email',
  uid_b: 'uid_bs_email'
  [,...]
},
names: {
  uid_a: 'uid_as_name',
  uid_b: 'uid_bs_name'
  [,...]
},
other_attribute: {
  uid_a: 'uid_as_other_attribute_value',
  uid_b: 'uid_bs_other_attribute_value'
  [,...]
}
```

Which you choose is a design choice, but thats the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing @Vincent answer, by default you can store the user name, email and photoUrl within firebase auth (read get user profile: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).

If you need to store more info, like postal address, phonenumbers, and so on, you can create a node in your database like `users` and store all the data you need. You can even use the same UID created for auth as the ID of your database. This way it would be easier for you to get user infos in the future.

When you just create the user with email and password, you can return the `user` and add it to your database with a script like this

```
firebase.database.ref(`Users/${user.uid}`).set({
name: this.state.name,
email: this.state.email,
});
```

Consider the code above just as an example.

Prefer to use `.set()` instead of `.push()`. If you use `.push()` firebase will create a random id which you will not be able to change. Using `.set()` you can determine the value of your node.

Hope it helps.

Comment: To store the user name and email in the firebase auth, I will not use the .createUserWithEmailAndPassword, right?

Comment: If you use `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` you must provide user's email. So, yes. You will use it to store the email in firebase auth. In `user` object (`firebase.auth().currentUser`) there's a property named `displayName` which firebase uses to store the authenticated user's name. So if you need only the user's name to be stored, you don't need to create a node for it in your database, you can just use the properties that `user` provides for you by default. However, if you are using any other auth type, you can just create a node `Users/` in your database to store it's data. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from the official documentation that might give you clue how to update and fetch data from database.

> **Set up Firebase Realtime Database for Android**
>
> *Connect your app to Firebase*
>
> Install the Firebase SDK. In the Firebase console, add your app to
>   your Firebase project. Add the Realtime Database to your app
>
> Add the dependency for Firebase Realtime Database to your app-level
>   build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2'
> ```
>
> *Configure Firebase Database Rules*
>
> The Realtime Database provides a declarative rules language that
>   allows you to define how your data should be structured, how it should
>   be indexed, and when your data can be read from and written to. By
>   default, read and write access to your database is restricted so only
>   authenticated users can read or write data. To get started without
>   setting up Authentication, you can configure your rules for public
>   access. This does make your database open to anyone, even people not
>   using your app, so be sure to restrict your database again when you
>   set up authentication.
>
> ***Write to your database***
>
> Retrieve an instance of your database using getInstance() and
>   reference the location you want to write to.
>
> ```
> // Write a message to the database
> FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
> DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
>
> myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
> ```
>
> You can save a range of data types to the database this way, including
>   Java objects. When you save an object the responses from any getters
>   will be saved as children of this location.
>
> ***Read from your database***
>
> To make your app data update in realtime, you should add a
>   ValueEventListener to the reference you just created.
>
> The onDataChange() method in this class is triggered once when the
>   listener is attached and again every time the data changes, including
>   the children.
>
> ```
> // Read from the database
> myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>         // This method is called once with the initial value and again
>         // whenever data at this location is updated.
>         String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
>         Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
>         // Failed to read value
>         Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
>     }
> });
> ```